# Four-function and exponentiation console calculator

Tags: c++, beginner, calculator

This code works as it is supposed to:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char cAgain, type;
    int x, y=0;
    double addition(double num1, double num2), subtraction(double num1, double num2), division(double num1, double num2), 
        multiplication(double num1, double num2), exponential(double num1, double num2), num1, num2, total;
    do
    {
        cout << "How many operations would you like to do?" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Error: You must have 1 or more operations." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            while (x != 0, x--)
            {
                y++;
                cout << "Enter in your "<<y<< " operation. (First Number (+,-,*,/,^) Second Number)" << endl;
                cin >> num1 >> type >> num2;
                switch (type)
                {
                case '+':
                    total = addition(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << "= " << total<< endl;
                    break;
                case'-':
                    total = subtraction(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << "= " << total<< endl;
                    break;
                case'/':
                    total = division(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " / " << num2 << "= " << total<< endl;
                    break;
                case'*':
                    total = multiplication(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " * " << num2 << "= " << total << endl;
                    break;
                case'^':
                    total = exponential(num1, num2);
                    cout << num1 << " ^ " << num2 << "= " << total << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Would you like to run the program again.(Y/N)" << endl;
            cin >> cAgain;
    } while (cAgain == 'Y' || cAgain == 'y');
return 0;
}

double addition(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 + num2;
    return (total);
}
double subtraction(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 - num2;
    return (total);
}
double division(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 / num2;
    return (total);
}
double multiplication(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 * num2;
    return (total);
}
double exponential(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = pow(num1,num2);
    return (total);
}
```

It starts by asking for the number of operations to perform. You enter a number, such as 3. Then it asks you to enter in your operation, such as 5+5, which is 10. Then it asks for a second, such as 10^2, which is 100. Then it asks for a third, such as 100-10, which is 90. Then it asks if you'd like to start over.

Comment: This is not the right place for such questions. Here, it is expected that you have working code but want to improve the quality of your code.

Comment: This code does work, wrote it without errors, I'm trying to improve the quality of the code by making it more user friendly. As it works now it works like your old school basic calculator it is hitting the = sign after every operation. I'm looking for a way to make it more like a modern scientific calculator.

Comment: Where's the modulo? :(

Comment: You should look up the `Command Pattern`. Then use a `std::map<char, Command>`

Comment: I have removed the off-topic part of the question. For inspiration, see questions tagged with [tag:math-expression-eval].

Comment: @200_success I did look through much of that that before posting. And considering that was the only question. I don't see how you see it as off topic, when it is the topic. It doesn't matter now as the question was already answered, but now anyone reading the response isn't going to understand it. I moderate other forums and understand why there is pruning. But if you're going to take out an entire question then link where I should be asking said question. Linking to a similar question that also has python, java, c# is difficult to sift through so link directly not generally before deleting.

Comment: That part was asking for additional implementation, which is on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a few issues here with c++ basics:

### using namespace std

```
using namespace std;
```

This is usually a code smell, generally speaking the only time you would really want to do this
is when you are making some small throwaway program for testing a concept or making an example (or similar).
In that case the reduction in typing time actually has a positive ROI.
But you don't want to do it in any production code because this pollutes the global
namespace which is something you should try to avoid, any benefit from time saved typing is
immediately wiped out the first time your program breaks because a name conflict.
See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more info on that.

If the main purpose for doing this is to cut down typing `std::` then you can
selectively bring in just the names you need by doing:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

an so on. This cuts down on typing without the downside of polluting the global namespace.

### Function declarations

Currently you have this line:

```
double addition(double num1, double num2), subtraction(double num1, double num2), division(double num1, double num2), 
    multiplication(double num1, double num2), exponential(double num1, double num2), num1, num2, total;
```

First of all, this line is way too many characters wide to be readable. But more importantly you are declaring some functions and some variables on the same line. This is very bad for readability. Some people only have one declaration per line, but at the very least don't have more than one type of thing being declared on the same line.

The idiomatic c++ way to do function declarations is at the top of the file or in header files. Instead put the function declarations above `main` one per line:

```
double addition(double num1, double num2);
double subtraction(double num1, double num2);
double division(double num1, double num2);
double multiplication(double num1, double num2);
double exponential(double num1, double num2);
```

This way it's much clearer to the readers of your code which functions you are forward declaring.

### Unnecessary variables

In each of the functions that computes the value of an expression you have the same structure:

```
double addition(double num1, double num2)
{
    double total;
    total = num1 + num2;
    return (total);
}
```

This can be simplified by just doing:

```
double addition(double num1, double num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

The reduction in the number of lines of code is a win for readability.

### Improving the features of the program

In order to compute the expressions such as `5+5^2-10` with correct operator precedence you will need to implement a parser. When I last did something like this I implemented a recursive descent parser. Be warned that this can be difficult to implement.

I would recommend reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

And looking into the [Boost Spirit parser](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) library.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm fairly new too coding and using namespace std; was just something my intro class added in as a starting standard code.

Comment: @Styx, I see that a fair bit, it just happens to be something that can turn into a bad habit if you use it for any real projects.

Answer (score 11):

I'll mention some additional points that haven't been mentioned yet, but this does look like it can still be cleaned out quite a bit.

- You could define those functions above `main()` so that prototypes won't be needed.  Otherwise, put them above `main()`, as already mentioned in another answer.
- These:

  > ```
  > #include<iostream>
  > #include<cmath>
  > #include<cstdlib>
  > ```

  would look nicer with spaces:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <cstdlib>
  ```

  Regarding spacing, you have some inconsistent spacing around the `case`s.  Try not to neglect this as it could make your code more awkward to read for others.
- `type`, `x`, and `y` are all declared outside of the loop, but are only used inside of the loop.  In order to help keep track of them, declare them right where they're first used.  Doing this with every variable can help with maintaining cleaner code, especially with larger programs.
- This is not doing what you expect:

  > ```
  > while (x != 0, x--)
  > ```

  The comma operator returns the result of the last expression, which is the `x--`. The other expressions are evaluated (from left to right) but the results of the expression are ignored.  Thus, the result of `x != 0` is evaluated with no side affects and the result dropped. This makes the expression equivalent to `while (x--)`.
- You don't check for division by 0, so your program can break if this operation is done.  You may throw an exception for that and handle it, so that you can get a different input.  Just make sure this division doesn't happen.
- You don't need `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  The compiler will do this return for you after reaching this point.

Comment: +1 Division by zero is a good point to mention, I totally missed that when I first glanced at the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor thing:

Instead of:

```
    total = addition(num1, num2);
    cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << "= " << total << endl;
    break;
```

you can make it like this:

```
case '+':
    cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << "= " << addition(num1, num2) << endl;
    break;
```

Comment: This may not work if the OP is trying to keep a running total.  To be fair, it took me a while to find `total` hidden behind the lines of prototypes.

Comment: probably, depend on him if he considered what @shuttle87 recommend, for sure he needs to keep total variable

Comment: @MORTAL as the program is currently programmed your improvements actually do simplify the code in a necessary way. Total will be needed after the code as implemented some of the improvements.